# QT Properties - Syntactic Sugar or Development Tools

Tags: qt, properties, metaclass

I'm sure all of you were at that point - defining a `Q_OBJECT` carrying a ton of `Q_PROPERTIES`, all with rather trivial accessors:

```
class ORM_Customer : public QDjangoModel
{
    Q_OBJECT  

    Q_PROPERTY(QString firstname READ firstname WRITE setFirstname)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString lastname  READ lastname  WRITE setLastname)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString phone     READ phone     WRITE setPhone)

    Q_PROPERTY(QString address1  READ address1  WRITE setAddress1)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString address2  READ address2  WRITE setAddress2)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString houseno   READ houseno   WRITE setHouseno)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString postcode  READ postcode  WRITE setPostcode)
[... snip ...]
}
```

with a ton of accessors all looking like that:

```
QString ORM_Customer::firstname() const { return m_firstname; }
QString ORM_Customer::lastname() const  { return m_lastname; }

void ORM_Customer::setFirstname(QString &n) { m_firstname = n; }
void ORM_Customer::setLastname(QString &n)  { m_lastname  = n; }
```

Given that QDjangoModel uses MetaObject introspection, I can't rely on dynamic properties here (besides, I like static properties) - question is, are there any tools that would save me the manual labor?

Qt Creator doesn't seem to have the option to just declare and define some default accessors and their respective private variables.. Anything else? It surely must've bothered more developers than just myself.

Or perhaps there is just another development pattern others use?

Comment: Yes, that's always bothered me. Q_PROPERTY always came across to me as sugar. You could always have a QVariantMap member with generic get/set functions. Or, if you prefer, a custom `enum` with a member `QHash<int, QVariant>`.

Comment: The only case when I would consider Q_PROPERTY is when developing a plugin for Designer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of a tool, sorry. But maybe you will get happy with Qt 5.1 when it is ready, because it extends the 'moc' compiler. See section "Essential Modules -> moc" in [Qt 5.1 feature list](http://qt-project.org/wiki/New-Features-in-Qt-5.1):

> New keyword in Q_PROPERTY: MEMBER let you bind a property to a class member without requiring to have a getter or a setter.